# Combining `replace` with `isnull` in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I try to select parts of a pandas series based on missing values of another series within the same data frame.

I  used `.loc`, a solution which works fine.

```py
df.loc[df["B"].isnull(), "A"] = np.NaN
```

Originally I wanted to use:

```py
df["A"].replace(df["B"].isnull(), np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

which is not working. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`replace` is used for replacing specific values—it does not work with boolean masks. If you wanted to mask elements, the correct function to use would be [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html).

```
df['A'].where(~df['B'].isnull(), np.NaN, inplace=True)
# or, more simply,
df['A'].where(~df['B'].isnull(), inplace=True)
# or,
df['A'].mask(df['B'].isnull(), inplace=True)
```

---

**Minimal Verifiable Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [np.nan, 1, np.nan], })
df
   A    B
0  a  NaN
1  b  1.0
2  c  NaN

# df['A'].where(~df['B'].isnull(), inplace=True)
df['A'].mask(df['B'].isnull(), inplace=True)
df
     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1    b  1.0
2  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Where is the difference between `mask` and `where`?

Comment: @ChrisBe `a.where(mask, b)` is the same as `np.where(m, a, b)` while `a.mask(mask, b)` is the same as `np.where(m, b, a)`.

Comment: @ChrisBe Here I will recommend `mask` because you don't have to invert the result of `df['B'].isnull()` afterward, it's a bit more efficient.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Thanks guys.